# Are there any javascript/jQuery events that are like an "onmousestop" or any events equivalent to "onmousewheel" for an optical mouse and/or touchpad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-inactivity

I am trying to create a Javascript-based inactivity timeout for my site. The function which controls inactivity is very simple; a form value recording the "initial time" is reset concomitantly with any event (the assumption being any event should be indicative of activity):

```
function ResetTimeout() {
    document.forms.TimeoutForm.initialtime.value = (new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
}//This function is called on each event, such as an onclick
```

In a separate function, when new Date().getTime() (that is, the time at this moment) - document.forms.TimeoutForm.initialtime.value (in milliseconds) > 720000 (12 min), a hidden logout form is submitted. Right now, I am binding these events to the `<body>` as follows:

```
<body onclick="ResetTimeout()" onkeydown="ResetTimeout()" onscroll="ResetTimeout()">
```

This works for almost all cases, since each page on my site requires a vertical scrollbar to see the bottom of the page. Any mouse or touchpad press is also captured, anywhere on screen. However, two valid outliers would be for (a) the user that never scrolls down, and never clicks the mouse/touchpad nor presses any keys but is still somehow engaged on the site and (b) the user that is (unlikely but possible) moving the mouse left/right but never scrolling, clicking, nor pressing any keys. Both of these users would technically be active on the site but would be considered inactive by my code.

I tried accounting for these users by binding the `onmouseover` or `onmousemove` events to the `<body>`, but these events are continuously triggered even if you do not move the cursor at all. I found HTML5's `onmousewheel`, but this does not work for an optical mouse nor touchpad (function never fires so event is never recorded even as you move the cursor all over the screen).

Is there an event in jQuery or Javascript that is recorded only whenever a user MOVES the mouse anywhere on the screen (and does not remain motionless)? That is, an event which fires only when xcoord2 - xcoord1 (or same for ycoord) does not equal zero over some time interval? My gut feeling is this may be complex and may require the code to record x or y coordinates at different time intervals and then compare. Alternatively, is there any event that would be something like `onmousestop` (a cursor-in-motion stops moving)? I read about "onwheel" (click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105815/touchpad-scroll-detection-in-js-no-library)) but I need something for all browsers. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: "*these events are continuously triggered even if you do not move the cursor at all*" - what makes you think that???

Comment: My bad..alert() kept getting fired even when cursor was stationary. I was corrected below by @adeneo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) event is not triggered unless the mouse actually moves

> The mousemove event is fired when a pointing device (usually a mouse) is moved while over an element

so simply

```
var timer;

$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        logout();
    }, 720000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Y8BxC/)

Comment: When I add onmousemove="alert('hey')" to the <body> tag the alert fires continuously (at least on my site) even when the cursor is stationary. Would this be any different if using jQuery? I'll give it a try regardless

Comment: That's because the event fires continously, and using an alert builds up a large queue that almost never ends, so your testing is wrong, see the attached fiddle