# Is it possible to trigger an event when the mouse stops moving?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an event that is triggered when a user has their mouse over a div element and while they're moving the mouse over the element.  However, I can't seem to find a way to trigger an event when the mouse stops moving.  For example, the event I'm working on checks if the user has the mouse over a div, if it is, then another element is shown and follows the mouse around.  When the user leaves the div, the shown element is hidden.  The way it works now is, I have the shown element showing and following the mouse around on the moused-over div, but it's not exactly what I want.  I'd like to have it not show when the mouse is moving, but show when the mouse has stopped moving.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tooltip"><p></p></div>
<div class="holder" id="1"></div>
<div class="holder" id="2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.holder{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0.25%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(100, 100, 0);
}
.tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

**JS**

```
var holder = document.getElementsByClassName("holder");
var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip")[0];
for(var i = 0; i < holder.length; i++){
    var moving;
    holder[i].onmouseover = function(ev){
        moving = false
        tooltip.style.display = "block";
        tooltip.style.top = ev.clientY;
        tooltip.style.left = ev.clientX;
    }
    holder[i].onmouseout = function(ev){
        moving = false
        tooltip.style.display = "none";
        tooltip.style.top = ev.clientY;
        tooltip.style.left = ev.clientX;
    }
    holder[i].onmousemove = function(ev){
        moving = true;
    }

    if(moving){
        tooltip.style.display = "none";
        tooltip.style.top = ev.clientY;
        tooltip.style.left = ev.clientX;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could implement some kind of timeout.. while mouse moving you clean and re-spawn a function..

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727394/are-there-any-javascript-jquery-events-that-are-like-an-onmousestop-or-any-eve

Comment: Awesome, thanks Erik and Max

Comment: Look for a `debounce` function instead of direct execution of the callback on the event. It delays execution for a short period. If a new event is called again in that period the callback is not performed, but the cycle starts again. Only after the last event the callback is executed. I your case, when the mouse stopped moving.

Comment: @Robert, I added a jQuery-less answer to the referenced http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727394/are-there-any-javascript-jquery-events-that-are-like-an-onmousestop-or-any-eve, since your question did not have the `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 1):

One naive approach would be set a timer when `onmousemove` is called. When the timer expires, do the hiding. When `onmousemove` is called again, reset the timer's timeout.

It's a judgement call for the application to make as to when someone stops moving the mouse. Technically a continuous movement of a mouse translates into a mouse move event per pixel.

You need to be a bit smart in doing this because onmousemove gets called a lot. So maybe something like this:

```
var mouseStartedMoving = false;
var mouseMoved = false;
const MINIMUM_MOUSE_MOVE_TIME = 100;

setInterval(() => { 
   if(!mouseMoved && mouseStartedMoving) {
       //Mouse stopped moving
       //Do CSS change
       mouseStartedMoving = false;
   }
   mouseMoved = false;
}, MINIMUM_MOUSE_MOVE_TIME);

holder[i].onmousemove = function(ev){
  mouseStartedMoving = true;
  mouseMoved = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using "setTimeout" function.

When you track mouse moves set "mouseMoved" to current millis. 
And then you do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

    var now = new Date();
    var nowMillis = d.getMilliseconds();
    var timeDiff = nowMillis - mouseMoved;
    if (timeDiff > 3000)
        alert("mouse stopped moving for 3 seconds"); 
}, 3000);
```